# jquery fadein problem

Tags: jquery

On my page, I put two divs: nav and contents.
Inside "nav", I have 10 links. Each one called like "link1", "link2",....
Inside "contents", I have 10 contens divs. Each one called ilke "divarea1", "divarea2",....
When I click link, new contents will fadein.
My jquery code is like:

```
$("#link1").click(function(){
  $("#divarea0,#divarea2,#divarea3,#divarea4,#divarea5,#divarea6,#divarea7,#divarea8,#divarea9,#divarea10").hide();
  $("#divarea1").fadeIn(3000);
});
$("#link2").click(function(){
  $("#divarea0,#divarea1,#divarea3,#divarea4,#divarea5,#divarea6,#divarea7,#divarea8,#divarea9,#divarea10").hide();
  $("#divarea2").fadeIn("fast");
});
```

This way works. But I know this is a stupid way. Someone can tell me how to do this in a simple way? thx

Comment: it will be helpful if you put your snipet html also here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $('#nav a').click(function(){
var idlink = $(this).attr('id').substr(4,2);
$('#contents div').hide();
$('#divarea"+idlink).fadeIn();
```

}

First, you listen to the click event on all the link in your #nav div. Then, on click, you get the id attribute and substract all the characters you don't need to only get the 'index' of the link.
You hide all the div in your #contents and fadeIn all #divarea that you want by using the index you got two lines before.

I'm not sure it's the best way, but it's better and it should work ! :)

Comment: I love this way. That's brilliant! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I see a couple of things we can do. We can use the [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) ability of jQuery and specify the two "dynamic" portions of your link: the content area to display, and the speed to display at. From there, we bind and pull those values from each link. Example:

```
<div id="nav">
  <a href="#" data-area="1" data-speed="3000">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#" data-area="2" data-speed="fast">Link 2</a>
  ...
</div>

$(function(){
  // locate and iterate over all the links in the nav container
  $('#nav a').each(function(i,e){
    // use the "data-area" to determine the content to display
    var area = $(e).data('area');
    // use the "data-speed" to determine how fast the content should be shown/hidden
    var speed = $(e).data('speed');

    // bind the click event
    $(e).click(function(e){
      // use a selector to find divs that match the prefix "divarea"
      $('div[id^=divarea]').hide();

      // now show the correct content using the two data fields we got earlier
      $('#divarea' + area).fadeIn(speed);
    });
  });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9ZmCr/)**

--

If you want to keep the link IDs, here is an alternative method. The anchor must still have the `data-speed`, but you can keep the id `linkN` (where `N` is a number):

```
$(function(){
    $('#nav a').each(function(i,e){
        var area = $(e).attr('id').match(/(\d+)$/);
        var speed = $(e).data('speed');

        $(e).click(function(e){
            $('div[id^=divarea]').hide();
            $('#divarea' + area).fadeIn(speed);
        });
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9ZmCr/1/)**

Comment: Thank you very much. But when I try these codes, it doesn't work. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest something like:
Add class "link" or whatever you want to each link and an id called something like "link_5", the number after the underscore being in relation with the div you wanna show.  So you must also add a class "nav" to all div in the "contents" wrapper with the id let's say "nav_5", number corresponding to the appropritate link. Then:

```
$(".link").click(function(){
  var id = $(this).split('_')[1]; //You get the id value after the underscore
  $('.nav').hide(); // You hide all div with the class "nav"
  $('#nav_'+id).fadeIn(3000); // You display the div with the id "nav_[id]"
});
```

Just so you understand completly, the .link class is for you a way to get all links with only one jquery request.  WEhen you click on the link, you split the id value to get the correct id for the appropriate content div.  This is a valid way on any browser and you dont get any "DOM" error in case you want to validate your website with W3C.  Hope it helps

Comment: the $('#contents div').hide() (previous answer) is actually better than adding class to each div.